# Are special characters allowed for an iPhone’s name?

Tags: iphone, ios

I know **how** to rename my iPhone.

I'm curious if there is any problem with adding a character to the iPhone's name.

Specifically, can I rename it to "**TMH's iP7+**" with the plus sign at the end?

I have looked online and cannot find any mention if this is an issue.

Answer (score 6):

Symbols are fine, including a plus sign or even emoji.

Answer (score 3):

You may notice oddness when sharing your Internet connection through Personal Hotspot. Some devices don’t play nice with non-Latin alpha characters, and may display funky characters in the list of Wi-Fi networks (though the connection should work fine).

I suppose your mileage may vary here, but other than that, [what @grgarside said](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/278343/11633).